# Pytest: unit test to reproduce OSError

Tags: python, exception, mocking, pytest, oserror

How do I reproduce OSError so that I can know that my exception works?

```
def write_file():
    try: 
        with open('file.txt', "w+") as f:
            f.write("sth")
        f.close()
    except OSError as e:
        logging.error("OSError occured")
```

I want to write unit test for the funtion `write_file()` using pytest. How do I mock the `OSError`?

Comment: Your code doesn't raise an `OSError` at the moment and you don't need to call `f.close()` when using a context manager.

Comment: @Alex In the case of file not found or sth, I want the exception to handle and test the content of the log. Is that possible?

Comment: @Alex: the point would be how to induce an error anyway.

Comment: @Jane: you are opening the file for writing, which means it will never raise an error for when the file is not found (it would be created in that case). You do get an `OSError` exception if the current working directory doesn't exist anymore or if the current user has no write access to the current working directory.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know, but this is something that would be needed for catching/detecting an OSError; and, as the comments have shown OP actually wants to capture the log so caplog, not pytest.raises

Comment: @Alex: no, there is no need to test if `OSError` is raised, the point of the test is to see that the code correctly handles `OSError` if raised by `open()`. The OP is not saying they were looking at `pytest.raises`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to mock out the `open()` call. You could do so with [standard library `unittest.mock.patch()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch), or with the [`pytest` `monkeypatch` fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/monkeypatch.html); I personally prefer to use the standard library here:

```
import pytest
import logging
from unittest import mock
from module_under_test import write_file

def test_write_file_error(caplog):
    caplog.clear()
    with mock.patch("module_under_test.open") as mock_open:
        mock_open.side_effect = OSError
        write_file()

    assert caplog.record_tuples == [("root", logging.ERROR, "OSError occured")]
```

The `mock.patch()` context manager setup places a mocked `open` object in the `module_under_test` global namespace, masking the built-in `open()` function. Setting the `side_effect` attribute to an exception ensures that calling the mocked object will raise that exception.

Mocking out `open()` is far easier than trying to create the exact filesystem circumstances in which the built-in `open()` function would raise an exception. Moreover, you are testing how *your own code* is handling `OSError` correctly, not if `open()` is working as designed.

Some side notes:

- There is no need to call `f.close()`; you are using the open file as a context manager (`with ... as f:`) and so it is closed *automatically*, whatever happens in the `with` block.
- The correct spelling is *occurred* (double *r*) :-)
- Don't use `except OSError as e:` when you don't intent to use the `e` reference to the exception; drop the `as e` part.
- If you use the [`logging.exception()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.exception), then the exception and the full traceback are captured in the log, as an `ERROR` level message.

```
def write_file():
    try: 
        with open('file.txt', "w+") as f:
            f.write("sth")
    except OSError:
        logging.exception("Failed to write to file.txt")
```

Comment: I'm always looking for solutions that do not use `unittest.mock`. Call me stubborn, but when I decide to use `pytest` I don't want to have to import `unittest` as well. I'm not convinced it's not possible to achieve the same results using the monkey patch features of `pytest` but hardly any answers ever demonstrate without `mock`.

Comment: Pytest `monkeypatch` can be used to patch the `open` builtin to raise the required exception: `monkeypatch.setitem(__builtins__, "open", _raise_oserror)` (where `_raise_oserror` is just a local function that raises `OSError`), but it seems `unittest.mock` patches a reference in the particular module whereas Pytest seems to patch the actual `__builtins__` itself. Pytest says it is ["not recommended to patch builtin functions"](https://docs.pytest.org/en/8.0.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html#global-patch-example-preventing-requests-from-remote-operations) because this might break Pytest.

Answer (score -1):

You want to do two things:

1. make `open()` fail with `OSError`. To acchieve that, [you could use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62055409/9096264)

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def change_test_dir(request):
    os.chdir('/')
    yield
    os.chdir(request.config.invocation_dir)
```

because I assume that you are not allowed to write in `/`.

2. You want to test whether the correct `logging` error is made. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53161880/9096264)