# Using Pytest and the Gitlab CI with relative paths

Tags: python, gitlab, pytest

I have an issue that is driving me mental and I can't get my head around it.

I am writing a little python App and wrote a few tests using pytest. For some of the tests, I need to load some files that are in subdirectories. It looks like this:

```
App/
   src/
      main.py

      logic/
         logic.py
         test_logic.py

         TestFiles/
             TestFile.json
```

Within the test_logic.py there is a test function that loads a file:

```
assert logic.load_file(TestFiles/TestFile.json) is True
```

When I run the function in PyCharm it works like (well...) charm.

My problems start when I try to simply run pytest from the terminal as because pytest is somehow in the wrong directory and gives me a `No such file or directory: 'TestFiles/TestFile.json'` error. I can work around this by navigating to the `App/src/logic`  directory and run pytest there.

However, when I try to use the CI pipeline from Gitlab the directory is wrong again and I can't properly navigate into the logic directory. Is there a way to a) tell pytest to  run only in a certain directory? `pytest /src/logic` does not work unfortunately. Or b) somehow tell the Gitlab CI to `cd` in the `logic` directory and run pytest there?

I feel like this should be a very easy question but I haven't been able to figure it out for almost 3h now...

**Edit:**

I get the following Error message when I start pytest from the root directory, as well as, in the Gitlab pipeline:

```
FAILED src/logic/test_file_interactions.py::test_load_from_py_file - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'TestFiles/No_Fields/Working_TESTFILE.py'
```

I also get this Error when I use `pytest /src/logic/test_logic.py`

I am on a Windows machine.

Comment: can you show us the output from the terminal running `pytest your-test-file.py`?

Comment: What is your `PYTHONPATH`? Are you on windows?

Comment: Not sure how your test are setup, but you could try mocking the working directory for tests to match whatever your "production" code expects https://stackoverflow.com/a/62055409/14536215

Comment: Regarding point B, why does that not work? In your `before_script` section simply `cd` to your target directory...

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Thank you for your super fast answer. I edited my question to give a few more information.

Comment: @TeejayBruno It kinda works to go into that directory (although the path starts with /builds) but pytest does not properly run from that directory as it would from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can infer the path of the `TestFile.json` at runtime from its relative location w.r.t. the `test_logic.py` file, something like this:

```py
import os

# __file__ is the path of the current file, in this case the path of test_logic.py
TESTFILE_FOLDER = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'TestFiles')

def test_load_file():
    test_file_path = os.path.join(TESTFILE_FOLDER, 'TestFile.json')
    assert logic.load_file(test_file_path) is True
```

Anyway, this approach is not optimal: you should move out the files with tests from the folder with the code of your package, storing them in a dedicated folder; you can find [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html) some best practices about how to structure the test folder for your package.

Moreover, if you need some additional resource to test your code, then it is better to store them in a separate folder, better if in the test folder. Then you can add a fixture in the [`conftest.py`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session) returning the path of that folder. In the `conftest.py` you can use the same approach I showed you here, inferring the path of the folder from the location of the `conftest.py` file.

Finally, if `TestFile.json` has only few lines, another approach could be to use [`mock_open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) and including the content of the file as a string in the test file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried both approaches, using the os.path.join and using the conftest.py. Both worked and I will stick to the fixtures in the conftest.py. Again, thanks for your help.